# Qhttp request and response debugging

Tags: qt, openssl

OS: Windows XP/Vista
Qt version: 4.6.1
Using OpenSSL

I need to watch the actual requests and responses that is going through the wire for QHttp requests and responses and in some cases need to interrupt the request. I tried with few of the http debuggers available in the market but they seem to work only for requests that are using the WinInet functions. Unfortunately, the openssldump utility is not present on windows platforms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't using QNetworkAccessManger instead of QHttp (which is obsolete) and reimplementing
[`QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest ( Operation op, const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData = 0 ) [virtual protected]`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest)
give you what you need?
Take a look at [How to tell QWebPage not to load specific type of resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575245/). This is for QNAM used by QWebPage but it's the same for any code using QNAM.